# Find and sum value of a datagridview column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to find and sum qty value of searched id in data grid view column am using this  code

```
Dim tqty As Double
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
    If row.Cells.Item(0).Value = cmbItemCode.Text Then
        tqty += row.Cells.Item(4).Value
        Textbox1.text=tqty
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The problem is that `Textbox1` shows only one top searched row value. For example

```
id     item name    qty
1      abc           4
2      xyz           10
1      abc           10
```

`Textbox1` shows the Result only 4.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you hit the first value, you exit the for statement.  Therefore you never get pass the first value.  Erase the Exit For it should work.

Comment: He should also wait with setting `TextBox1.Text` until _after_ the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If DataGridView2.RowCount > 1 Then
            Dim tqty As Integer = 0

```
        'if you have the other column to get the result you  could add a new one like these above 
        For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
            amount += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value)

            'if you have the other column to get the result you  could add a new one like these above (just change Cells(2) to the one you added)
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = tqty
```